# Method not found Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder onmodelcreating

Tags: entity-framework-core, com-interop, .net-standard-2.0

I have a unit test that calls a .net472 com visible library
which in turn calls a .netstandard2.0 library

An error occurs with call stack

```
 System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!0,System.Object>>)'.
   at SBDSTD.Standard.Entities.ApiDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at MySTD.Standard.Helpers.LogHelper.InnerLogMessage(String message, JobHeaderLogInfo logInfo, Boolean sendEmail, ApiDbContext connect)
```

... rest of call stack starting with unit test.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8467

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be because my .net472 library had some unneeded references to entity framework
[This issue prompted me to delete them](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8467)